# React JS and laravel passport POST method chenged to OPTIONS

Tags: reactjs, laravel-passport

When i was tried to add Authorization code in react js custom header .. **POST** method changed to **OPTION** method .

```
 fetch('http://localhost:8000/api/user/save', {
        method : 'POST',
         headers: {
            'Accept' : 'application/json',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
            'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + sessionStorage.getItem('token')
          },


      body : formBody

    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(response => {

     }).catch((err) => {
             alert('Something is error   ! ');
     });
```

**Note :** I want to use cross origin . My react app on localhost:3000 and my server localhost:8000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of CORS, if your API and the front end lives on the same project you can just change `http://localhost:8000/api/user/save` to `/api/user/save`.

You can also disable CORS.

Comment: I want to user another domain name .  like as my domain name is http://localhost:300 But i want to POST localhost:8000

Comment: @SagarRoy you're going to have to disable cors

Comment: can you give me a example how can i disable cors

Comment: I think this problem about front (react app) not in laravel . Also i want to use Post method not OPTION .

Comment: @SagarRoy please read what CORS is when your browser makes a request it will do a pre-flight request under the method options. You can't make the full request because the backend is sitting on a different domain. This has nothing todo with your front-end.